# Yes/No question: Binominal statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, binomial-distribution

I'm stuck on how to analyse one of the questions for my survey. My question asked whether the therapist's surveyed felt their style of intervention changed depending on the setting. I received 31 responses, with 19 responding Yes, and 12 responding No. 
I'm trying to work out whether this is a significant different, but am unsure whether a binominal distribution would be appropriate, or whether to use a z-test? 
I'm very inexperienced with statistical analysis, and any response would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would not do significance testing in this setting but rather calculation 0.95 confidence intervals for proportion of yes.  The Wilson interval is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your response @FrankHarrell. I've calculated the results using the Wilson interval, and have come up with  prevelance of .61, Lower 95% CL 0.44, and Upper 95% CL as 0.76. I'm unsure how to interpret the upper and lower confidence intervals, but feel that as the prevelance is relatively close to .5 there isn't a large difference between the two votes?

Comment: Not clear on "two votes".  I didn't see a confidence interval for a difference but only a confidence interval for a proportion.

Comment: Thanks again for your response @FrankHarrell. How would I write up these results in a journal article? I've been looking online but haven't been able to find any solution

Comment: Simplify the wording and turn it into a problem of estimating a proportion of "Yes".  Give the proportion and its 0.95 confidence limits.

Comment: @FrankHarrell, That makes complete sense and has really helped me, thank-you so much for your input!